# What's changed in the recent versions of Dapper?

Tags: .net, dapper

I see a 1.9 and 1.10 release of dapper.net at http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/list

What's changed in these new versions?  Is there a change log somewhere?

Did the query cache ever get fixed so that it won't grow indefinitively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind.  I just found the following in the nuspec file:

```
  * 1.13   - Added support for Table Valued Parameters as part of anonymous objects
  *        - Added support for async
  *        - Added support for sharing strategies between databases
  *        - Rewrote dynamic implementation
  * 1.12.1 - Minor deploy glitch (should now include intellisense files!)
  * 1.12   - Better automatic type-mapping (int vs long, float vs double, etc)
  *          Fixed: bug with indexer properties
  * 1.11   - Custom type-map support
  * 1.10   - Fixed: error-handling could lose original exception if reader closed
  * 1.9    - Added: better schema change detection
  *          Fixed: enum support for T in Query-of-T
  *          Added: dictionary support for parameters
  * 1.8    - Started release notes
  *          Important: Dapper is now shipping as a DLL which will work on .net 3.5 or .net 4.0,
  *          This improves the debugging experience as you no longer break into dapper when SQL fails.
  *          Added: ParameterNames on DynamicParameters
```